# API Integration across multiple accounts within same organization

Tags: docusignapi

I have had my API Integration promoted to my Production environment for a few weeks now and all is well but I ran into a new issue that I need help understanding. The process is setting up impersonation. The hierarchy of the organization is relatively simple:

[image]

My Integration was built under Company A and so far 100% of Company A accounts are able to be impersonated as expected. The issue came up when Company B was added to the Organization and one of the existing accounts was included in the list to be impersonated. The following message is what I am getting back from my API call.

[image]

I have Organization Admin permissions as well as Admin permissions on all of the Company Accounts too and this message appears even for me. My feeling is this is a simple administrative function to grant the User in Company A the permissions to access either a User in Company B or all of Company B. I am just not seeing where this gets setup. I hope anyone can point me in the right direction on this one.

=== 07/06/2022 - Adding additional details ===

/oauth/userinfo respose...

```
    {
        "sub": "xxxxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxxx",
        "name": "Greg Miller",
        "given_name": "Greg",
        "family_name": "Miller",
        "created": "2017-11-10T18:26:23.583",
        "email": "greg.miller@companyA.com",
        "accounts": [
            {
                "account_id": "xxxxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxxx",
                "is_default": true,
                "account_name": "CompanyA",
                "base_uri": "https://###.docusign.net",
                "organization": {
                    "organization_id": "xxxxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxxx",
                    "links": [
                        {
                            "rel": "self",
                            "href": "https://account.docusign.com/organizations/xxxxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxxx"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "account_id": "zzzzz-zz-zz-zz-zzzzz",
                "is_default": false,
                "account_name": "CompanyB",
                "base_uri": "https://###.docusign.net",
                "organization": {
                    "organization_id": "zzzzz-zz-zz-zz-zzzzz",
                    "links": [
                        {
                            "rel": "self",
                            "href": "https://account.docusign.com/organizations/zzzzz-zz-zz-zz-zzzzz"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

[image: Admin panel User Membership screen]

### Additional Info Added 07/07/22

Both Company A and Company B base_uri designation is the same "https://na2.docusign.net"

This is the /oauth/userinfo data returned using the JWT created for the Company B user account I am trying to impersonate.

```
{
    "sub": "xxxxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxxx",
    "name": "Company B",
    "given_name": "CompanyB",
    "family_name": "XYZ TEAM",
    "created": "2021-03-31T18:20:05.23",
    "email": "xyzteam@companyb.com",
    "accounts": [
        {
            "account_id": "xxxxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxxx",
            "is_default": true,
            "account_name": "Compan B",
            "base_uri": "https://na2.docusign.net",
            "organization": {
                "organization_id": "xxxxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxxx",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "rel": "self",
                        "href": "https://account.docusign.com/organizations/xxxxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxxx"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The steps I take are basically the same as you outline:

1. Generate JWT Access Token
2. I am manually storing the required userinfo data userID(sub) and base_uri in a local db table.
3. I am using CURL to make my API calls " $base_uri.'/restapi/v2.1/accounts/'.$AccountID.'/views/console'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices for accessing data in Company B (Account B):

1. Add the user in Company A (Account A) to also be a user in Account B. (Users can have `memberships` in more than one account.)
2. To access the data in Account B (Company B), impersonate a (different) user who is in account B. This is done via the eSign Admin app or via the Org Admin app.

By design, a user who is not in Account B cannot access any data in Account B.  (This is the error message you're receiving.)

Note: you do **not** need to make any changes to your app's integration key (client ID)--all client IDs in production can be used with any user, with any account the user has access to.

To see which accounts the current user has access to, use the [/oauth/userinfo](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/) API method.

### Added

When you get the message *User does not have a valid membership in this account* check:

1. What account is the request using? (What is the URL of the request?)
2. Was the request sent to the right `base url` for the account?
3. What result does the **current access token** provide when calling the /oauth/userinfo API method.

Your test API calls should be:

1. Get an access token
2. Call /oauth/userinfo
3. Call the eSign API (eg list envelopes or somesuch) for each of the accounts listed in /oauth/userinfo

Comment: Thanks for the details you provided. I am an admin in all three entities (Org, Company A & Company B) and I am also getting this message. ran the API you suggested and I do show to have membership in Company B. I have also looked in the Org Admin panel and it also reflects my membership in both Companies. I am going to edit my original question and add details showing the API results and Org Admin panel.

Comment: See additions to my answer. HTH.

Comment: Now that I look at the #3 answer, will the account_id need to change for each company user? My answer to #2 above does not include the account_id and my gut tells me that this is where the issue lies since there is no CompanyB-UserID(sub) in CompanyA and a membership does not resolve that match up. uuuggg...

Comment: I just realized that the PostMan Collection is automatically saving the account_id when I make an auth call so I am convinced this is what my issue is above. Since PostMan made this variable change, I completely missed this value as a necessity till I added that second Company entity where it would matter. I am going to go through and see if I can verify this and will post the results.

Comment: Yes, this is validated... I changed the static account_id from Company A to that of Comany B. I was still able to authenticate since I exist in both Company instances and I was able to impersonate the specific Company B User account that I was getting the error on previously. When I tried to impersonate any user from Company A, the same error appeared. Since the error appears inversely to which account_id I specify, I am 100% certain this is the solution. Thank you for your assistance on this Larry K...!!!